# Will removing Windows 8 and disabling secure boot cause any problems using Ubuntu?

Tags: laptop, windows-8, uefi, secure-boot

I heard that recent laptops with Windows 8 enable secure boot which can cause problems while installing or using Ubuntu, and I'm worrying because I have a plan to buy a Dell Inspiron 15z with Windows 8 but want to use Ubuntu with no problem.

If I remove Windows 8 from my Windows 8 pre-installed laptop and disable the secure boot option, will Ubuntu install normally and run with no problem?

Thanks for answering :)

Comment: I think Ubuntu will work fine, but why not buy a computer with Ubuntu preinstalled? That way you are 100% sure it will work, and you don't pay for Windows. You can buy them at [System76](http://www.system76.com) for example.

Comment: @com.BOY This is [not the right place](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) for shopping recommendations.

Comment: @gertvdijk _ Well, IMO, a link where one can find linux/ubuntu compatible hardware is, IMO, on topic. It is not advice for a specific piece of hardware, but I can also see where is a bit borderline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Dell XPS that came shipped with Windows 8.  I turned off secure boot in the bios and used Ubuntu 12.10 install disc.  I was able to install it side by side Win 8 with no problems.  At startup and I an option now that allows me to boot using the windows UEFI mode, or something similar, or just boot in Ubuntu.  Both work fine.

Retrospectively, I don't think that I needed to turn off secure boot in the BIOS.  I am not sure what it actually did but I think Ubuntu was clever enough to figure it out for me.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :) It was helpful for me Thanks!

Comment: @SongYoung-woon If this answer solved your question, please click the checkmark next to this answer.